# Pygame.update does not update after each round

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to explosion to occur instantly or very fast. Is there a way to speed up the formation of the circles or to display the formation of each circle instead of forming all 20 and then displaying?

Ive tried asking many people, my teacher, youtube, and playing around with the location of pygame.display.update()

```
def explosion(x,y):
    explode = True
    while explode:
        startpoint = x,y
        colorchoice = [red,yellow,black,white]
        magnitude = 1
        while magnitude < 20:
            boom_bit_x = x + random.randrange(-1*magnitude,magnitude)
            boom_bit_y = y + random.randrange(-1*magnitude,magnitude)
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorchoice[random.randrange(0,4)],(boom_bit_x, boom_bit_y),random.randrange(4,7))
            magnitude += 1
            pygame.display.update()
        explode = False
```

Comment: Have you considered that the problem might not be that it's going too *slow*, but that it's going too *fast*, and updating with all 20 circles before you can see it? IF you put, say, `time.sleep(0.033)` (1/30 of a second) right before doing `pygame.display.update()`, does it fix things?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I get an error saying 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: @AT42 Use `pygame.time.delay(33)` instead (33 milliseconds == 0.033 seconds).

Comment: @Rabbid76 It does not work. Instead of that, is there a way for the explosion to form very fast and to speed up the formation of the circles?

Comment: Or put `clock = pygame.time.Clock(); clock.tick(30)` just after `pygame.display.update()`

Comment: @kiner_shah It doesn't change anything. Still takes 3 seconds to form the explosion.

Comment: @AT42, then instead of `clock.tick(30)`, you can use `clock.tick(60)` or even higher. Lower value for tick means less refresh rate, means slower animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```py
def explosion(x,y):
    explode = True
    while explode:
        startpoint = x,y
        colorchoice = [red,yellow,black,white]
        magnitude = 1
        while magnitude < 20:
            pygame.event.pump()
            boom_bit_x = x + random.randrange(-1*magnitude,magnitude)
            boom_bit_y = y + random.randrange(-1*magnitude,magnitude)
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorchoice[random.randrange(0,4)],(boom_bit_x, boom_bit_y),random.randrange(4,7))
            magnitude += 1
            pygame.display.update()
        explode = False
```